# using command prompt how can i change my gmail username on my local account back to microsoft

Tags: windows, windows-10, gmail

Using command prompt, how can I change my Gmail address username on my local account back to Microsoft.  It doesn't let me sign in.  You see my Gmail address but when I put my password in, it said to change my Microsoft password to sign in.  But it's not a Microsoft account.  Somehow I ended up with my Gmail address as my sign in local account.  I also don't see the option of changing my username.  I can only sign in as a built-in administrative.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a command prompt instead of using the interface?  Its not as simple as just disconnecting the Microsoft Account, you have to create a local user account, all of that would be really complicate with a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft allows the use of any email for a Microsoft account, which means that you signed up for an account using your gmail and linked it to your computer.

Go to [Microsoft's account page](https://account.microsoft.com/about) and click login. Use the recover password prompt which should send a link to your GMail account. Once you change the password, you should be able to instantly log into your account.